# Abstract Classes and Virtual Methods- Creating objects for each of the classes and displaying results

Tags: c#

I have been newly introduced to the world of C#. I am now learning how to use abstract classes and virtual methods inside a windows form. I have the structure/idea but need help filling up with code my form.  My base abstract class is named `Plants`, four subclasses named `Trees`, `Tomatoes`, `Seeds` and `Berries`,  one virtual method named `Get_value` and method named `Report` that is outside of all the methods.

I would like for `button1` click create at least two objects for each of the classes and display them in a multiline `textBox1` using calls to `Report` and on another `textBox2` to show the value of each type of plant and the total value of all the plants.  Any ideas or help on how would I be able to go about this?

**CODE**

```
namespace plant_farm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public abstract class Plants
        {
            protected string the_name;
            //may need more strings but not sure

            public virtual string Get_Value()
            {
                return "";

                /*
                   Multiplies the number of items times the value per 
                   item and returns the product as a double.
                */
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {

                return "";

              /* 
                Returns a string that gives all the relevant information 
                for the object(including an indication of wheter it is a 
                tree, seed, etc.
              */


            }
        }

        public class Trees : Plants
        {
            /*
              Includes a variety(oak, cherry, etc.), height in feet,
              the number of trees in stock, and the price of each tree.
            */
        }

        public class Tomatoes : Plants
        {
            /*
              Includes: Type(big boy, early girl, etc.), the size of the 
              tomatoes expected (small, medium, or large), the price of each plat,
              the number of plants per plat (6, 12, 24, etc.) and the number of 
              plats in stock.
            */
        }

        public class Seeds : Plants
        {
            /*
              Includes: Type of seeds(pumpkin, cantaloupe, cucumber, etc.), 
              the number of packets in stock, and the cost per packet.
            */
        }

        public class Berries : Plants
        {
          /*
           Includes: Type of plant(blackberry, strawberry, etc.), the variety
           (AAA early, FrostStar, etc), the month of highest bearing (May, June,
           etc.), the number of plants in stock, and the price per plant.
          */
        }

        public void Report()
        {
            /*
            Is passed a Plant object and a TextBox and adds the ToString result of 
            the object to the textbox and then skips to the next line.
             */
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague. I would recommend to keep reading a bit more, specifically on the difference between inheritance and composition. Inheritance is an "is a" relationship where composition is a "has a" relationship.

Tree "is a" plant, Tomato plant "is a" plant. Berry "is a" seed (not a plant) Plants "have" seeds.

This would lead to a structure where the abstract class for Plant would contain a Seed instance which itself was an abstract base class for Berries, pine cones, nuts, etc...

Ultimately this is probably a very bad example to try working with because you can go nuts with the inheritance which is generally a bad idea, especially for a beginner.

Start instead with understanding composition, then Polymorphism through Interfaces, then move on to Inheritance with Abstract Classes and virtual members.